# Exclude a file from dependency

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies

I am using `jython-slim-2.7.2.jar` in my Spring Boot application. This JAR file contains a file I don't need. I want to remove that file without manually deleting it (by opening the JAR from local repository and then deleting the file). How can I configure Maven to delete that file while building executable JAR?

Comment: What is the problem with the file? Does it hurt if it is present?

Comment: Ist it a `.class` file you don't need? If you don't need it simply don't use it. Or ist there an identically named class file within the same package in your classpath coming from some other dependency?

Comment: It is not a .class file. It is a .whl file.

Comment: @JijoAntony Please explain and add to your question (via the _Edit_ link under the tags) why you want it to be not present. Without any further information the chances for hints or an answer are not very high.

Comment: @Tomerikoo What's the reason for eliminating the [whl] tag? Did you see \@Jijo Antony's comment? My work on the according tag wiki page has also been [thrown into the waste bin](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/whl/info). That's not fun. :(

Comment: @GeroldBroser I'm sorry about your work on the wiki, but I don't see anything in the question regarding whl. Comments shouldn't be accounted for and any relevant information should be directly inside the question. Feel free to add that information and then add the tag...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I'm not going to add this to the question. It's not mine and I don't know \@Jijo Antony's environment or use case (yet). That's why I also voted to close with _Needs details or clarity_. And, couldn't you have added the information rather than removing the tag. ;)

Comment: @GeroldBroser To be honest, I didn't read the comments, which is exactly why they shouldn't be counted on and any information needs to be directly in the question... Lastly, tags should indicate what the question is *about*, not what it *contains*. After reading the question and comments again, I don't see how the question is about whl (but then again, I'm not an expert so I might be missing something crucial)